# Hibernate duplicate field mapping on Pojos

Tags: java-8, hibernate-mapping, netbeans-8

I'm trying to generate my persistence layer with hibernate 4.3 and mysql 5.6 on netbeans 8.1, but each time it creates duplicated fields.

here is an example of what I'm getting:

---

```
 private Set<Cliente> clientes = new HashSet<Cliente>(0);
 private Set<Cliente> clientes_1 = new HashSet<Cliente>(0);
 private Set<Compra> compras = new HashSet<Compra>(0);
 private Set<Compra> compras_1 = new HashSet<Compra>(0);
 private Set<Cotizacion> cotizacions = new HashSet<Cotizacion>(0);
 private Set<Cotizacion> cotizacions_1 = new HashSet<Cotizacion>(0);
 private Set<Credito> creditos = new HashSet<Credito>(0);
 private Set<Credito> creditos_1 = new HashSet<Credito>(0);
 private Set<Cuenta> cuentas = new HashSet<Cuenta>(0);
 private Set<Cuenta> cuentas_1 = new HashSet<Cuenta>(0);
```

This problem is on each entity generated by hibernate. I also tried with the latest hibernate version which is 5.2 and the same problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, if you update from old version of hibernate to new version (4.3 to 5.2) when the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto* is set to **update, it forces hibernate to recreate the constraints, leaving the old ones in the db, when that happens the next time you try to recreate the persistence layer hibernate does not understands the old constraints as a relationship and so it creates the new properties.